# javax.sql.DataSource connection pool Confusion

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I want to implement a connection pool into my java web application for a MySQL database. Whilst looking online, I found a few guides to change my DriverManager based connection to one that utilised the DataSource type.

From what I can tell from [a tutorial I found from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#pooled_connection), DataSource automatically produces connections from a built in connection pool, in particular, this section.

> The variable ds represents a DataSource object that produces pooled connections to the database COFFEEBREAK. You need to retrieve this DataSource object only once because you can use it to produce as many pooled connections as needed. Calling the method getConnection on the ds variable automatically produces a pooled connection because the DataSource object that the ds variable represents was configured to produce pooled connections.

However, I found some places saying that DataSource doesn't facilitate connection pooling and that ConnectionPoolDataSource is the type that does. So I'm a little confused by this.

So does DataSource do connection pooling? if it does, does it automate it? do I set up all of my servlets with an initialisation to set up a connection? Is there a more straight forward guide/resource to learn about this from?

sorry for the string of questions, any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've missed the point completley. The prior several paragraphs talk about using *specific* implementations of `DataSource` that *do* provide connection pooling. Apache DBPC is one such. The tutorial then goes on to show that using such a source is syntactically identical to using any other `DataSource.`

Comment: You should never use an implementation of `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` directly, it is intended to be used by connection pools, it does not (or should not) provide connection pooling by itself.

Answer (score 1):

`DataSource` is an interface, and just by looking at it you can't know if it does pooling or not. In any case, you can always use your own explicit connection pool (I'm partial to HikariCP), so you don't need to guess and you'll know exactly what you're doing with your pool.